# select multiple cells in a table with the same value in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

i tried this code:

```
SqlCommand selectcurrentuserid = new SqlCommand("select ID_UTENTI from UTENTI where USERNAME_UTENTI='" + Login.currentUser + "'", conn);
currentuserid = (int)selectcurrentuserid.ExecuteScalar();
SqlCommand selectarea = new SqlCommand("select ID_AREA from VISUALIZZAZIONE_UTENTI where ID_UTENTE='" + currentuserid + "'", conn);
msa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from AREAGEOMETRY1 where AREAGEOMETRY_PROTEZIONE='false' or AREAGEOMETRY_WINAAREA_ID='" + (int)selectarea.ExecuteScalar() + "'", conn);
msa.Fill(data);
```

but in this way the command selectarea select only the first ID_AREA and not all the ID_AREAs that have the same value.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and what you expect the result to look like please?

Comment: i want that the datagrid (data) displays all the items that have the same ID_AREA.

Comment: Maybe you have only one row for `ID_UTENTE` that has `currentuserid` value? Have you ever tried your queries on your sql server and see what results return? But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Well, `.ExecuteScaler` **by definition** only reads the **first row, first column** of your dataset - you're shooting yourself in the foot! You need to use `.ExecuteReader()` and then iterate over the rows being returned by the reader!

Comment: soner gonul, i want that the command gives me all the cells(ID_AREA) that have the ID_UTENTI equals to currentuserid (a integer variable)

Comment: @paololalalla Then your `selectarea` seems fine to me. Are you aware you should not use single quotes with integers?